# What is the space complexity of a recursive function that searches a BST? - O(h) or O(log(n))?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, space-complexity

So I have written some code for a `BST`, where I am looking for whether a `target node` is contained in it.

At every `recursive call`, half of the tree gets 'eliminated', i.e. we reduce the number of nodes we need to `search for in half`. Now while I know this equates to `O(log(n)) space`, is it not also equivalent to the height of the tree `O(h)`?

As a visual example, please see below:

[image]

Say we are looking for 14 in our BST, the most number of recursive calls will be equal to the height of the tree, 3? Is this correct? And I imagine this extends to the general case too? As I can't think of an example where this would not be true.

Comment: Your reasoning presumes that the tree is balanced, which is not necessarily true in the general case. If the tree is balanced, its height *is* O(log(n)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BSTs `h` corresponds to `log(n)` only when the tree is perfectly balanced, while in general your search will be `O(h)`.

Take for example the case of a tree completely skewed to one side, like this:
[image: chain bst tree]

The tree's height here is `7` and the worst case is where will you be searching the last node, performing 7 steps into the tree, so not a `log(n)` complexity.

Comment: Indeed, consider the worst case where the tree is completely left or right skewed. In this case, O(h) implies O(n) in number of nodes.

Comment: Perfect, that makes complete sense now. I didn't think about it in terms of different cases of the trees; just assumed it would normally not be balanced.